# Interesting use for Okra as the main ingredient in a dish?

Tags: okra

I had a few handfuls of fresh Okra delivered with the last CSA delivery. I'm looking for an interesting way to cook a dish featuring it. I also have:

- One eggplant
- Some pumpkin
- One leek
- Lots of tomatoes
- Cilantro
- Dill
- Potatoes

Comment: If you do some poking around online, you can find people who blog about how they use the produce they get from CSAs; maybe you can find one in your area, so it'll be similar produce they write about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okra is great in curry.  I'll do an okra and tomato curry, but you can find plenty of recipes online.

Comment: I ended up making my own Garam Masala and using it along with tomatoes and garlic as a base for a tasty curry

Answer (score 1):

Okra + tomato is halfway to gumbo and other similar dishes. In fact, this is what I intend to do the next time I can get okra.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting challenge.  How about this:

Skin and slice the eggplant, about 1/2" 1.3 cm thick, salt lightly and press the sliced stacked salted eggplant for a while to densify it.  After a half hour or so, rinse and dry the eggplant, cube it and dredge in seasoned flour if you have it.  Skin and cube the potatoes put them in a large hot pot with some kind of fat in it and brown the potatoes.  When they are about done add the cubed eggplant, then add the washed and sliced leek.  Put in some garlic too if you have and want to use it.  When the eggplant is slightly browned add stock or water or combination of ingredients, could include beer wine or ?, I find I don't like cooking with IPA or really hoppy beers as it adds more bitterness than I like.  This would be a good time to add a bay leaf if you have one.

Next peel, quarter and seed the tomatoes, peel and cube the pumpkin and slice the okra to your preferred size and add them to the stock.

If you have flour and know how to do it make a medium brown roux and add it when the pumpkin is done.

Season to taste and yum! Garnish with fresh dill and cilantro.

```
* One eggplant
* Some pumpkin
* One leek
* Lots of tomatoes
* Cilantro
* Dill
* Potatoes
```

Comment: LOL, you mentioned all other ingredients but left out the Okra :)

Answer (score 0):

Okra is a magical vegetable whose texture varies dramatically depending on how it's cooked.

BBC has [Okra recipes and information](http://www.bbc.co.uk/food/okra)

- Main course
- Light meals & snacks
- Starters & nibbles

Some of Okra recipes from India

http://www.nandyala.org/mahanandi/archives/category/indian-vegetables/okra/

http://www.physiology.wisc.edu/ravi/okra/#recipes

http://hubpages.com/hub/Okra-Ladys-Finger-Recipes